# About asynchronous methods and threads

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, thread-safety

What actually happens behind the scenes with asynchronous functions?

Does it open a new thread and let the OS start and run it?

If so, can it cause deadlocks or other thread problems?

Here's an example of a async method:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = process.argv[2]

fs.readFile(file, function (err, contents) {
  var lines = contents.toString().split('\n').length - 1
  console.log(lines)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fs.readFile(file,callback)`.This is a non-blocking call which means.

1. node's main thread stores the `callback` in event-table and
   associate it with an event which will be emitted whenever file
   reading process is done.
2. By the same time node has several internal threads(thread pool) from
   which node's main thread assign file reading task to one of the
   thread.
3. After this assignment the command is returned to main thread and
   main thread continues with the other tasks and file reading process
   is being done in background by other thread(not main thread).
4. Whenever file reading process is completed the event associated with
   the `callback` is emitted along with the data from file and that
   callback is pushed into `task-queue` where event loop tries to push
   each task to the main thread(stack).
5. And when main thread(stack) becomes available and and there is no
   task present before the `callback`'s task this callback is pushed to
   main thread's stack by the event-loop.

Please read [event-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for more info.

So the thread which is responsible for file reading doesnt cause Deadlock to othere threads.
It simply emit exception or success which is later handled by the `callback`

Comment: So we don't have to worry about thread problems when using Node's async functions?

Comment: Yes.
You don't have to.Because any exception happening will be handled by the callback.