# How nodejs is handling the non-blocking IO eventhough it is single threaded?

Tags: node.js

Iam new to nodeJS. I want to know how nodejs is handling the non-blocking IO eventhough it is single threaded. 
Gone through so many articles, still those didn't clarify my doubt.

Please some explain this with the help of example/diagram that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most recommended resource https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Here is the things which can help you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js/14797359#14797359

Comment: Thanks abdulbarik, that video really helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Node JS Single Threaded Event Loop Model.**

Please check [here](http://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop) for more details with diagrams.

Some more links which help you like as follows :

1. [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html)
2. [Why is Node.js single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959663/why-is-node-js-single-threaded)

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 1):

Node JS works on single thread that doesn't mean if it is exactly having 1 thread. Actually it has a pool of worker threads which it uses to perform I/O operations.

> While i/o operations are being performed by other threads the main
>   thread is idle to receive any input operation. [See it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971952/about-asynchronous-methods-and-threads/38972632#38972632)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a useful link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js)

Hope this will give a further better understanding for single threaded node js execution.

Comment: It should be in comment box not as an answer, FYI above comment link is same